# modpagespeed overrides cachecontrol of static content in apache

Tags: apache, cache-control, mod-pagespeed, mod-expires, mod-headers

currently the version 1.9.32.14-r0 of mod_pagespeed running on the webserver

purely static content (not pagespeed cached) is served with first max-age=300 and counting downward to max-age=0 and starting again with max-age=300

when mod_pagespeed is disabled then mod_expires/mod_headers continuously displays the .htaccess configured max-age=2692000

i don't see the reason why

`.htaccess:`

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2692000 seconds"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 <FilesMatch "\\.jpg$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"
 </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 4):

I did manage to find a partially sufficient answer.

One Option I found in [Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mod-pagespeed-discuss/R9C19a7O-Yk/QlANF6ciBAAJ) is to turn off IPRO. `ModPagespeedInPlaceResourceOptimization`. This in turn means the resources need to be optimized hardcoded. This can be found in [documentation](https://modpagespeed.com/doc/system#ipro).

```
ModPagespeedInPlaceResourceOptimization off
```

Added in Version 1.9.32 the default cache time can be set. `ModPagespeedImplicitCacheTtlMs` found in an related [issue](https://github.com/pagespeed/mod_pagespeed/issues/989). you can find this in [documentation](https://modpagespeed.com/doc/system#implicit_cache_ttl) too.

```
ModPagespeedImplicitCacheTtlMs 604800000
```

Comment: In addition to the ModPagespeedImplicitCacheTtlMs there is a new setting as of 1.9.32.2 which appears to fix this problem by providing a default cache TTL for resources that are loaded from file.  See https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/system#load_from_file_cache_ttl